# Why the spark in a lighter is blue and can it be white as a lightning is?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, temperature, lightning

Is lightning white due to moving electrons or nearby nitrogen,oxigen and water vapour atoms and can a simple lighter spark glow white?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're talking about eletric lighters.

In both cases the air ionizes and what you see is a plasma.
Now the color blue/purple makes sense for the energy and the oxygen/nitrogen.

Can it be white, that's a bit more difficult to answer.
Let's start with why lightning is white, Lightning is also a plasma and white doesn't make that much sense based on the air composition. It's white because of the extremely high temperature/energy density and it's especially white when there's low air humidity (less contamination, higher temp). It's not actually white, it actually radiates all colors in the visible spectrum that humans than perceive as white (similar to blackbody radiation).
This video, https://youtu.be/VXm3zDM_v80 actually shows the spectrum and the actually color of lightning simultaneously, the ball on the left is the actual color, and the spectrum/line on the right is the lightning split up over the different colors in the visible spectrum.

So can a lighter give a white plasma spark, questionable, I don't know what temperature you would exactly need to reach white and thus this temperature/energy-density might be unreasonable to achieve in a simple lighter.

Some more indications as what the colors (tinged) of lightning usually indicate.
https://www.wfmz.com/news/what-color-is-lightning/article_b65b63c8-7cd1-56d0-b909-88ac635edc8b.html

This scientific paper actually tries to estimate the temperature of ligthning based on the plasma generated https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320656562_Calculating_the_electron_temperature_in_the_lightning_channel_by_continuous_spectrum
Peak temperature is about 25 000K (Kelvin or Celsius doesn't matter much at those temperatures). For Refercence, the SURFACE of the sun is about 5500K to 6000K

If you want to see some (crazy) smart guy generate white plasma (and other colors)
https://youtu.be/UNisqZOAaAs

Comment: But is white radiation emitting body cooler than a blue one...  as I anderstood Your answer should a lightning be blue/violet due to a so high temperature?

Comment: It's emitting, all colors at once, so red to green, to blue to violet. However since it's so much light, your eyes will see it as white. Sunligth also emits the entire spectrum, but you also perceive it as white light. Screen (tv/phone) also make white by emitting red, green and blue light at the same time.
Usually the whiter the light and more intense, the hotter the source, at least for black body radiation.
Plasma has some line colors but for these cases that shouldn't matter too much and it will also be washed out by the white so you won't see it usually at high energy/temperatures.

Comment: Talking about sunlight, Sun temperature is 6000 K but all hotter stars emit blue/violet. Why do You think lightning should be white due to temperatures that cause UV, rendgen, violet and blue emitions? A gas tourch as you add oxigen to increase the temperature starts to glow red then yellow, white and finaly blue?

Comment: Look up scientific literature dude and read up how black body radiation and light works. White light from the sun also contains violet and blue light, you just experience it as white. Same with hotter stars. However stars that are very far away get red shifted. If you are going to make these kinds of things provide proper sources. Did you even read my entire post and the sources I provided?

Comment: Are all  red and blue stars red or blue only due to redshift or also due to surface temperature?

Comment: No not all of them, but the ones you can see with the naked eye should be (however I'm not a 100% sure and would need to check it properly).
So the short answer is the ones you can normally see, are red-shifted if they do not appear whitish. However I'm not an astronomer and things are a bit more complicated in practice then just considering black-body radiation. Blue stars might be slightly different but there's only so much I can explain in 500 characters and only so much I know. Very bright blue stars are probably extremely hot and emit so much blue/violet that they wash out the red.

Comment: Also note that just because peak temp of lightning is 25 000K doesn't mean that's it's average temperature or the most prevalent temperature for emitting light. Also they are often TINGED blue and purple. However I had to explain it all it would probably get too complicated and long stretched considering what was asked and how it was asked.
(Ps sorry if I came off a bit harsh in my previous answer)

Comment: @BobvandeVoort When performing double slit experiment with let say pure blue coherent light the central fringe which has the most intense light is more white than blue....is this same that happens with lightning?